# WPF и обращение к объектам в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Собственно, есть у меня DataGrid, источником данных для которого является список объектов. Мне нужно, чтобы при выборе строки выполнялся один из методов объекта, которому соответтвует выбранная строка. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под выбором строки?

Comment: Я уже разобрался. Там нужно добавить неявное преобразование (Item)Grid.SelectedItem.

Comment: Да, ну и почитайте про привязку и MVVM

Answer (score 0):

[DataGrid.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditem(v=vs.95).aspx) возвращает тип `object`.

К примеру в качестве `ItemsSource` для вашей таблицы `MyGrid` был выбран `List<Item>`. Тогда чтобы при нажатии мыши обратиться не к строке таблицы, а к объекту её породившему, необходимо написать

```
Item item = (Item)MyGrid.SelectedItem
```